# USB MIDI interface detected but not connected

Tags: windows, usb, midi

Currently I am developing a USB MIDI interface. Recently I ran into a problem with this interface. Windows 10 is able to install all the correct drivers and MIDI in/out is detected correctly. But when I tried to communicate with the interface I can't send any MIDI message.

MIDI-OX cannot connect:

[image]

It worked previously until I messed around with some USB key in Windows10 registers. I have used USBdeview to remove the USB device and start from zero, but it didn't work.

DeviceManager:

[image]

What is happening with it? Any idea for debbuging this problem?

Comment: What board is this?  What did you change in the registry?  Can you use something like USBTrace to see if the underlying USB device is getting opened?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I didn't know about USBTrace. I will take a look at it. I think it may help.